# After reboot, bluetooth is active, but pairing no possible

Tags: usb, 22.04, bluetooth

A similar question was asked three years ago, with no answer.

After reboot of my `Ubuntu 22.04`, I always need to unplug-plug my `ASUS USB-BT500` bluetooth stick so that keyboard and mouse can connect. Rarely a similar effect happens during a session (keyboard and mouse disconnect, and reconnect after unplug-plug).
I have tried `usbreset` without success.

The following settings are equal after reboot (no connection) and unplug-plug (connected):

```
kjo@one:~$ lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0b05:190e ASUSTek Computer, Inc. ASUS USB-BT500

kjo@one:~$ rfkill --output-all  
ID TYPE      DEVICE TYPE-DESC   SOFT      HARD  
1  bluetooth hci0   Bluetooth   unblocked unblocked
```

// Added on Nov 8:

1. The firmware does not seem to be the problem:

   ```
    kjo@one:~$ sudo dmesg|grep Bluetooth
    ...
    [   11.020767] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
    [   18.756496] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: HCI_OP_READ_LOCAL_VERSION failed (-110)
    [  302.409688] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0a hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0a lmp_subver=8761
    [  302.410650] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
    [  302.410652] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin
    [  302.412865] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_config.bin
    [  302.413178] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 6, total sz 30210
    [  302.561736] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0xdfc6d922
   ```
2. But the timeout at [   18.756496] might give a hint?

// more observations:

- The fw is installed in the right places (since it is automatically loaded after bt-dongle is inserted)
- According to dmesg, the fw is not loaded at reboot, even if the dongle is connectd at boot-time. dmesg prints a timeout error `HCI_OP_READ_LOCAL_VERSION failed (-110)`
- The fw is loaded when the bt-dongle is inserted

// added Dec 23:
// after reboot, stick is plugged in, bt does not work:

```
kjo@one:~$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
DOWN 
RX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 events:0 errors:0
TX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 commands:1 errors:1
Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Packet type: DM1 DH1 HV1 
Link policy: 
Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT
```

// after removing and inserting the stick, bt works now:

```
kjo@one:~$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
BD Address: 08:BF:B8:48:4D:B4  ACL MTU: 1021:6  SCO MTU: 255:12
UP RUNNING PSCAN 
RX bytes:7328 acl:268 sco:0 events:302 errors:0
TX bytes:35232 acl:91 sco:0 commands:200 errors:0
Features: 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xfe 0xdb 0xfd 0x7b 0x87
Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT 
Name: 'one'
Class: 0x6c0104
Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Audio, Telephony
Device Class: Computer, Desktop workstation
HCI Version: 5.1 (0xa)  Revision: 0xdfc6
LMP Version: 5.1 (0xa)  Subversion: 0xd922
Manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Corporation (93)
```

// some more searching:
// after reboot, stick plugged in, bt not available:

```
kjo@one:~$ sudo hciconfig hci0 up
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)
kjo@one:~$ sudo hciconfig hci0 reset
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)

kjo@one:~$ bluetoothctl list
kjo@one:~$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# pairable on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent is already registered
```

// after removing and inserting the stick, keyboard and mouse connect:

```
[NEW] Controller 08:BF:B8:48:4D:B4 one [default]
[NEW] Device CB:01:A5:7C:EE:54 TrackPoint Keyboard II
[NEW] Device D9:07:F2:94:63:8F ERGO M575
[NEW] Device E4:F8:EF:53:B8:BA kjo
[NEW] Device E0:9F:2A:18:7F:C8 Intuos BT S
[CHG] Controller 08:BF:B8:48:4D:B4 Powered: yes
[CHG] Controller 08:BF:B8:48:4D:B4 Alias: one
...

kjo@one:~$ bluetoothctl list
Controller 08:BF:B8:48:4D:B4 one [default]
```

What can I do to avoid the unplug-plug?
Thanks for help

Karl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to follow a proposal I found in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1310775/bluetooth-adapter-not-detected-on-linux), but could not find an option to disable/enable BT in my BIOS. BUT since I quit BIOS and restarted the system, BT just worked and **my problem is solved**.

Answer (score 0):

USB-BT500 has the Realtek 8761BU chipset. This chipset is known to be incompatible with Linux. The recent Linux kernels can make it work, but you need to plug into your PC after each startup and after each wake-up from suspend. Also, during use, you may encounter times when the bluetooth disconnects abruptly.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Since it works after pluging in, is there no possibility to trigger the same even (whatever this is) from a script that runs after the boot process?

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 links for solving the problem by installing the correct driver.

Please let the community know if the install solves the problem.

https://tutorialforlinux.com/2021/12/28/rtl8761b-bluetooth-driver-ubuntu-20-04-installation-step-by-step-guide/

https://github.com/Elif-dot/RTL8761BU

Comment: Thanks Rob. The two links explain how to install the firmware and provide the firmware itself. But as you can see from the dmsg output, the firmware is not the problem: 
[  302.410650] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[  302.410652] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin
[  302.412865] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_config.bin
[  302.413178] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 6, total sz 30210
[  302.561736] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0xdfc6d922

Comment: oops, sorry for the formatting. I will include that i my original question. Plus one more info, that might give a hint to the real problem.

Comment: pls post the results of:  hciconfig -a